# Can these two bash commands be joined into one?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, short

I've been trying to get the following two commands into one command:

```
var=$(find dir/* -name "$file")
var=$(basename "$var")
```

I thought this might work:

```
var=$(basename $(find dir/* -name "$file"))
```

I also tried pipeline, but no luck

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another set of quotes:

```
var=$(basename "$(find dir/* -name "$file")")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-exec` option of the command `find` to apply the `basename` command on each result:

```
var=$(find dir/* -name "$file" -exec basename {} ';')
```